# How to check a IP-Header or TCP/UDP header is in a connection?

Tags: tcp, header, udp, ip

I've a firewall to detect all connections.
When I've a connection from A to B, we receive many packet sending between A and B.and if we make a connect from B to A, we also receive the result is the same A->B.

I don't know how to check each packet is belong the connection that A created or B created.

I've captured IP header, TCP/UDP header, but I don't know what's the field that cans check it.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence number field is what you need.

```
struct tcphdr {
    unsigned short  th_sport;   /* source port */
    unsigned short  th_dport;   /* destination port */
    tcp_seq th_seq;         /* sequence number */
    tcp_seq th_ack;         /* acknowledgement number */
...
};
```

```
    packet A -> B

    A [th_seq=1] -> B
    B [th_seq=2, th_ack=1] -> A
    A [th_seq=3, th_ack=2] -> B
```